# Application_Start() gets called more than once

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have an application made on asp.net MVC 2 and it is on IIS 7.5 on my pc I tried profiling it and I noticed that Application_Start gets called **more than once**,
 
**does anybody knows why is this happening ?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `Application_Start` event is fired once when the application domain is loaded. If you see it firing more than once then this would mean that the application restarts. There are multiple reasons an application domain could get unloaded like deleting modifying some of the files like `web.config`, the `bin` folder, ... Here's an [article describing common reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johan/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle) for application restart.

Comment: For me, it was writing files to the bin folder.

Comment: @d512, I was running in a performance issue for 2 days, your simple comment fixed it in few seconds!

Comment: @SamehDeabes Glad to hear it! Always nice to know you helped somebody out.