# Azure web apps life cycle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-applications

How often does a web app (in Azure) restart?

For example with a MVC application:
How often is the `Application_Start()` method in the `global.asax.cs` called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't Azure-specific. ASP.NET Web Applications run in `w3wp.exe` and can be killed and recycled by IIS at any time, without warning. The first request after a kill will cause `Application_Start` to be invoked again.

Depending on how active your website is, IIS may kill your website after a period of inactivity (to free-up memory), on the next request to your site IIS will relaunch the application and call `Application_Start`.

There are also circumstances where `Application_Start` will be called more than once for a single application initialization, though this is usually due to a misconfiguration:

- [Application_Start() gets called more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003670/application-start-gets-called-more-than-once)
- [Multiple Application_Start events firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685158/multiple-application-start-events-firing)